# HTML Canvas: Fill() not working with no errors in console

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Hello I am making a polygon and want to fill it up. But whatever I try to do I can't seem to make it work.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I appreciate it.

https://jsfiddle.net/ygesj1do/4/

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
op = {
  "pts": [{
    "x": 40,
    "y": 13.5
  }, {
    "x": 60,
    "y": 27.75
  }, {
    "x": 60,
    "y": 56.25
  }, {
    "x": 40,
    "y": 70.5
  }, {
    "x": 20,
    "y": 56.25
  }, {
    "x": 20,
    "y": 27.75
  }],
  "color": "#00F",
  "fillcolor": "#FF0000",
  "lineWidth": 1
};

ctx.save();
ctx.strokeStyle = op.color;
ctx.fillStyle = op.fillcolor;
ctx.lineWidth = op.lineWidth;
ctx.beginPath();

for (i = 1; i <= op.pts.length; i++) {
  if (i == op.pts.length) {
    ctx.moveTo(op.pts[i - 1].x, op.pts[i - 1].y);
    ctx.lineTo(op.pts[0].x, op.pts[0].y);
  } else {
    ctx.moveTo(op.pts[i - 1].x, op.pts[i - 1].y);
    ctx.lineTo(op.pts[i].x, op.pts[i].y);
  }
}

ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use `moveTo()` once for each path after `beginPath()` then just use `lineTo()` after that.  Once you do all of the `lineTo()`'s in the `for` loop, then you can do the `ctx.fill()` to get it to work.

Here's the updated part of the code:

```
/* set moveTo() once before for loop */
ctx.moveTo(op.pts[0].x,op.pts[0].y);



/*then in the for loop just use lineTo(), using lineTo() will keep track of the last endpoint on the current path so you don't need to use moveTo() unless you are starting a new path.*/

        for (i=1;i<=op.pts.length;i++) {
            if (i==op.pts.length) {
                ctx.lineTo(op.pts[0].x,op.pts[0].y);
            } else {
                ctx.lineTo(op.pts[i].x,op.pts[i].y);
            }
        }

/* now the following will work */
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does! Thank you. If I set the `i` in the for to 0 instead of 1 it works without the move to before the loop. Is that a bad practice or does it work?
If its ok the if is no longer needed. The loop then becomes:

for (i=0;i<op.pts.length;i++) {
 ctx.lineTo(op.pts[i].x,op.pts[i].y);
}

Comment: So according to MDN's canvas tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes, you don't have to use moveTo() after beginPath() per se, this is just used to move the coordinates, it's not required. Also using fill() automatically closes the path but stroke() does not, so you can call stroke() first, and then fill(), and leave out the closePath() and it will have the same result with one less line of code